# Given individual probabilities of n independent trials, how to calculate probability exactly k are successful?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given the individual probabilities `P_i` of n independent trials, 1≤i≤n, how can I calculate the probability exactly k trials are successful?

In the special case k=n, the probability of n successes is simply the product of the probabilities. But how can I calculate the probability of k successful trials for 1

Small examples I can calculate by hand:

1. `P = [0.8, 0.7], k=1. The probability exactly one trial is successful is 0.8*(1-0.7) + (1-0.8)*0.7 = 0.38
2. `P = [0.8, 0.7, 0.6], k=2. The probability exactly one trial is successful is 0.8*0.7*(1-0.6) + 0.8*(1-0.7)*0.6 + (1-0.8)*0.7*0.6 = 0.452

But this school method doesn't scale to large examples, because there are 'n choose k' terms in the sum. For example with n=50, k=20, P=[0.01,0.03,0.05,...,0.99], there would be "50 choose 20" terms, which is 47129212243960. Surely there must be a simpler way to calculate the probability.

Comment: Do you want an exact answer, or a good approximation?

Comment: A good approximation can always be found by MC simulation.

Comment: You can compute the probability in O(nk) time and O(k) space using dynamic programming.

Comment: You've made a calculation error in example 2: you've replaced 0.6 with 0.3 in the second term.

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `P(i, j)` be the probability that there's `j` successes in the first `i` trials.

Then `P` satisfies:

```
P(0, j) = 1 if j == 0 otherwise 0
P(i, j) = p_i * P(i-1, j-1) + (1-p_i) * P(i-1, j)
```

Here's a short Python program that computes the probability in O(nk) time and O(k) space, essentially using the above recurrence relations for each `i` iteratively. After `i` iterations of the `p` loop, the array entries `P[j]` holds the values of `P(i, j)`. The code runs the three examples in your question (including the difficult one with n=50, k=20). The results are exact fractions, and the code runs essentially instantly.

```
from fractions import Fraction as F

def prob(ps, k):
    P = [1] + [0] * k
    for p in ps:
        for j in xrange(k, -1, -1):
            P[j] = p * (P[j-1] if j>0 else 0) + (1 - p) * P[j]
    return P[k]

for tc in [
        ([F(8, 10), F(7, 10)], 1),
        ([F(8, 10), F(7, 10), F(6, 10)], 2),
        ([F(1, 100) + F(2, 100) * i for i in xrange(50)], 20),
        ]:
    print 'ps = [%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, tc[0]))
    print 'k = %s' % tc[1]
    print 'probability = %s' % prob(tc[0], tc[1])
    print
```

Output:

```
ps = [4/5, 7/10]
k = 1
probability = 19/50

ps = [4/5, 7/10, 3/5]
k = 2
probability = 113/250

ps = [1/100, 3/100, 1/20, 7/100, 9/100, 11/100, 13/100, 3/20, 17/100, 19/100, 21/100, 23/100, 1/4, 27/100, 29/100, 31/100, 33/100, 7/20, 37/100, 39/100, 41/100, 43/100, 9/20, 47/100, 49/100, 51/100, 53/100, 11/20, 57/100, 59/100, 61/100, 63/100, 13/20, 67/100, 69/100, 71/100, 73/100, 3/4, 77/100, 79/100, 81/100, 83/100, 17/20, 87/100, 89/100, 91/100, 93/100, 19/20, 97/100, 99/100]
k = 20
probability = 6354741607005879635747506856181887568383689465714196334804901357522358768197915724707861/204800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `P_i` are not assumed to be equal, the exact analytic expression is difficult to calculate, as you have noted, because of the large number of terms. The probability can be expressed as

`Q[k] = sum[ subsets S of size k from n elements ] prod [indices j in S] P_j prod [indices l not in S] P_l`

There are a lot of repeated terms in the product, and we could hope that this expression could be factored somehow. First note two things: this expression is a polynomial where each term either contains `P_i` or `1-P_i`. Consider all the terms in the sum that include `P_i`. Factoring `P_i` out of this, the remaining part is is

`sum[ subsets S' of size k-1 from n-1 elements (no i) ] prod [indices j in S'] P_j prod [indices l not in S'] P_l`

This is another type of the same quantity you are computing, only where the index `i` is left out. Denoting this `Q[k-1,-{i}] (i.e. k-1 terms, leaving out the set of indices {i}), and making a similar observation for the remaining terms containing`1-P_i`, the overall quantity`Q[k,-{}]` can be computed using

`Q[k,-leftout] = P_i Q[k-1,-(leftout U {i})] + (1-P_i) Q[k,-(leftout U {i})]`

where `i` is some index not in the set `leftout`. This does not give a closed-form formula for your quantity, but can be computed using DP, as noted by @PaulHankin in the main comments.

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution gives highly accurate approximations near the expected number of terms.  Each binary probability `p` has expected value `p` and variance `p(1-p)`.  So add them up and you get the expected number, and variance.  From that you get the appropriate approximating normal distribution.  The probability density of that normal distribution near `k` is close to the probability of getting `k`.

For an exact answer, just do dynamic programming to walk the array of probabilities and track the odds of each possible outcome.  Be warned that the numbers near the tail quickly get incredibly small.